# A cast to int has gone wrong. android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

im having an issue while video mixing with audio. everytime when I try to make it.
That always give me an error which is

> Java.lang.RuntimeException: A cast to int has gone wrong. Please contact the mp4parser discussion group.

Im using googlecode mp4 parser : `implementation  com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22` and also tried that but no success  `implementation 'org.mp4parser:isoparser:1.9.41'`

Also on forum there's no proper answer on that question.

here's my code

```
 public Track CropAudio(String videopath, Track fullAudio) {
    try {

        IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(videopath);

        double lengthInSeconds = (double)
                isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getDuration() /
                isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getTimescale();


        Track audioTrack = (Track) fullAudio;


        double startTime1 = 0;
        double endTime1 = lengthInSeconds;


        long currentSample = 0;
        double currentTime = 0;
        double lastTime = -1;
        long startSample1 = -1;
        long endSample1 = -1;


        for (int i = 0; i < audioTrack.getSampleDurations().length; i++) {
            long delta = audioTrack.getSampleDurations()[i];


            if (currentTime > lastTime && currentTime <= startTime1) {
                // current sample is still before the new starttime
                startSample1 = currentSample;
            }
            if (currentTime > lastTime && currentTime <= endTime1) {
                // current sample is after the new start time and still before the new endtime
                endSample1 = currentSample;
            }

            lastTime = currentTime;
            currentTime += (double) delta / (double) audioTrack.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
            currentSample++;
        }

        CroppedTrack cropperAacTrack = new CroppedTrack(fullAudio, startSample1, endSample1);

        return cropperAacTrack;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fullAudio;
}


public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {


            Movie m = MovieCreator.build(video);


            List nuTracks = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                if (!"soun".equals(t.getHandler())) {
                    nuTracks.add(t);
                }
            }

            Track nuAudio = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(audio));
            Track crop_track = CropAudio(video, nuAudio);
            nuTracks.add(crop_track);
            m.setTracks(nuTracks);


            Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
            FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(output)).getChannel();
            mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
            fc.close();

            try {
                Variables.closeProgressDialog();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(Variables.tag, e.toString());
            } finally {
                Go_To_preview_Activity();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Variables.closeProgressDialog();
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong"+ e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Go_To_preview_Activity();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(Variables.tag, e.toString());

        }

    }

};
```